# Doubt on plotting bivariate Gaussian contours

Tags: normal-distribution, computational-mathematics, python

So I'm trying to understand the implementation of a function that plots the bivariate normal contours of two variables. Thought I'd post here since the question is primarily mathematical in nature and the code itself isn't too complicated.

The following code is given in one of the lectures of an online ML course:

```
def plot_contours(mu, cov, x1g, x2g, col):
  rv = multivariate_normal(mean=mu, cov=cov)
  z = np.zeros((len(x1g),len(x2g)))
  for i in range(0,len(x1g)):
    for j in range(0,len(x2g)):
      z[j,i] = rv.logpdf([x1g[i], x2g[j]]) 
  sign, logdet = np.linalg.slogdet(cov)
  normalizer = -0.5 * (2 * np.log(6.28) + sign * logdet)
  for offset in range(1,4):
    plt.contour(x1g,x2g,z, levels=[normalizer - offset], colors=col, linewidths=2.0, linestyles='solid')
```

We specify a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector `mu` and covariance matrix `cov`. If $n_1=$`len(x1g)` and $n_2=$`len(x2g)`, then we're looking to calculate the probability density at all points in $\{0,1,\ldots,n_1-1\}\times\{0,1,\ldots,n_2-1\}$.

My question is: if the purpose is to plot contours of the normal probability density, why do we use the `logpdf` function? The descriptions of the functions are [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html):

> `pdf(x, loc=0, scale=1)    Probability density function.`
>
> `logpdf(x, loc=0, scale=1) Log of the probability density function.`

Any particular reason of using `logpdf` and then proceeding to calculate other stuff like the log of the determinant and a normalizing term? Couldn't we just have calculated the pdf like:

`z[j,i] = rv.pdf([x1g[i], x2g[j]])`

feed this into the `contour` function and be done with it?

Comment: Sure you could, why not try it? Usually the log transform smooths peaks in the density out leading to nicer plots. Because the logpdf of a Gaussian is "quadratic term" + "normaliser" this code is discounting the normalising term to give you nice integer spaced contours of the quadratic term, or something like that

Comment: @Nadiels: Thanks! So you mean that the reason behind using logpdf is to just smooth out how the plot would look like? Let's say I'm trying to code an algorithm which uses the bivariate normal probability at various points in the grid: I can just use the normal pdf, right? No analytical advantages of using the log transform (only a visual advantage)?

Comment: Depends a little bit on what your application is -- the logpdf avoids the exponential so is more stable, but if your application actually requires the values of the density then for most, if not all, the continuous distributions in something like scipy, the .pdf(x) method is actually implemented as np.exp(self.logpdf(x)), or equivalent.

Comment: @Nadiels: That's very useful info. I'll keep that in mind!